# Query google analytics API by Group Name

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Google analytics API gives you an ability to query content by a content group (ga:contentGroupXX). However, I can't find a way to filter out a specific group name. For example, I have a group for Pants and I set it like this.

```
ga('set', 'contentGroup1', 'Pants')
```

How can I get views for that specific group name? This is how I am pulling the entire content group via the api:

```
ids=ga%xxx&dimensions=ga%3AcontentGroup1&metrics=ga%3Ausers
```

I need something like this:

```
ids=ga%xxx&dimensions=ga%3AcontentGroup1Pants
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a filter:

```
ids=ga%xxx
&dimensions=ga%3AcontentGroup1
&metrics=ga%3Ausers
&filters=ga%3AcontentGroup1==pants
```